# Undocumented behaviour in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is the following behaviour documented (i.e. should I rely on it)?

Due to an error, I had a dialog box and referred to its id using a bare word in javascript. Surprisingly, I did not get an error and the code worked as intended,

The example (on JSFiddle.net [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N4Axw/)) has a 2 simple dialog boxes

```
<div id="Hello">
   <input id="box1" name="box1" type="text" value="not change">
</div>
<div id="Goodbye">
   <input id="box1" name="box1" type="text" value="not change">
</div>
```

And javascript which is missing the line `Hello = $("#Hello");`.

```
$("#Hello").dialog({
    autoOpen:false, 
    modal:true, 
    width:"auto"}
);
$("#Hello").dialog("open");
$("#Goodbye").dialog("open");
$('[name="box1"]',Hello).val("test");
```

Surprisingly, the last line updates the textbox in the `Hello` div, but I can't find anywhere where this behaviour is documented. Is it just an obscure side effect, not to be relied on, or is this a valid jQuery selector style?

FYI, I'm using Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107 m.

Comment: It would work even if you had something else there because `[name="box1"]` is a valid selector and the 2nd parameter is `undefined`, which is essentially the same as not specifying the parameter in the first place.

Comment: The point is that is I open up the Chrome developer tools and simply type the name in the console (i.e. `Hello` in the example), I get the `<div...>` displayed, indicating that something has defined it.

Comment: See Kevin.B's answer. It seems it's the browser not jQuery, but it's still not documented anywhere clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior. Since you have an element on your page with the id "Hello", a property is automiatcally defined on window that points to that element, equivalent to:

```
window.Hello = document.getElementById("Hello");
```

this has been around for quite a while in all browsers, i'm not exactly sure where or even if it is documented. jQuery is not doing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/w4YJw/

It is typically suggested to not rely on this since it can be easily broken by defining a variable named the same as the id. It also breaks some functionality, for example, giving a submit button `id="submit"` will make it impossible to call `form.submit()`

Comment: So it's actually the browser not jQuery?

Comment: Is it search id only ??

Answer (score 1):

`$('[name="box1"]',Hello)`queries the DOM for elements which have attribute `name` equals to `box1`, hence your fiddle works. Second parameter would be the context, but being it `undefined`, jQuery resolves it to the whole `document`.

[Anyways, the behaviour is documented here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).

Comment: My example was unclear. In the real page, there are multiple inputs with the same name, but it selected the right one. I've updated the JSFiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery constructor should still work, you've just passed in `undefined` for the context, an it's still able to find an element with the name "box1" in the document-scope.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in this same fiddle example:

```
$(text).val("test");
```

It put value of input field because it finds it in attributes & matched it